# How do I get iOS 5 on my iPod touch?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ios, ipod

I have a third generation iPod touch. I believe that it should be possible to run iOS 5 on this, and I have bought an app that requires iOS 5.  However, in iTunes, when I click on the iPod device, it says that my iPod software is up to date. It says that the software version is 4.2.1. I'm registered with Apple with a Belgian account, though I hope this wouldn't make a difference to updates.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: My guess is it is an 2nd gen iPod touch. Have you confirmed that it is 3rd gen?

Comment: Did you try steps in http://www.macworld.com/article/162925/2011/10/how_to_upgrade_your_ios_device_to_ios_5.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apple](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html), the 3rd gen iPod Touch can be upgraded to iOS 5. However, you may want to confirm that your iPod is not a 2nd gen version - those can only be upgraded to 4.2.1.

[Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1353#iPod_touch_late2009) has the following information to confirm your version ([full page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1353)):

> iPod touch (3rd generation) features a 3.5-inch (diagonal) widescreen
>   multi-touch display and 32 GB or 64 GB flash drive. You can browse the
>   web with Safari and watch YouTube videos with Wi-Fi. You can also
>   search, preview, and buy songs from the iTunes Wi-Fi Music Store on
>   iPod touch.
>
> The iPod touch (3rd generation) can be distinguished from iPod touch
>   (2nd generation) by looking at the back of the device. In the text
>   below the engraving, look for the model number. iPod touch (2nd
>   generation) is model A1288, and iPod touch (3rd generation) is model
>   A1318.

Also, per [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4972) - make sure that you've upgraded to iTunes 10.5 before you begin the upgrade.

Comment: Indeed, it is a second generation iPod.  I thought that I'd checked that already, but not with a reliable soure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update iTunes to version 10.5 before you update your iPod. The 3rd generation should update to iOS 5. To check the iPod version number follow this KB article.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1353?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Had already updated to the latest iTunes. Thanks anyway.